# Issues resolving glide library with latest gradle/android studio march 2018

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My project is failing to resolve the [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library after updating Android Studio and gradle. My project is using `gradle version:4.4` and `android studio version: 3.1`. Here is the list of repositories in my gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }

    }
}
```

Is anyone else encountering the same problem?

Comment: will you please more about your issue, this is not sufficient to get what you ae facing.

Comment: The exact error my gradle build is getting is `Failed to resolve:glide`

Comment: `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.+'`
`annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.+'`

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your gradle:-

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.+' 
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.+'
}
```